# any gae framework for GAE User registry without Google Accounts

Tags: jquery, python, validation, google-app-engine, web-applications

i want to find a webapp framework for validation  user , store user,

and  has ajax  Effect of jquery ,

so ,did you know this simply framework  ?

thanks

like this page : [http: //digu.com/reg](http://digu.com/reg)

Comment: Please revise your question. It is way too hard to undersand. We need detail and grammar.

Comment: a gae frame for user  Registration

Answer (score 3):

OpenID is now supported (experimentally) in App Engine 1.3.4.  See [Nick's Blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Using-OpenID-authentication-on-App-Engine) for a nice tutorial about setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [http://gaeframework.com](http://www.gaeframework.com) - with local user registration